# Cannot see bugs in DevOps KanBan when specifying subarea

Tags: azure-devops, process, agile, kanban

I have a DevOps account with a project in it. I am using the Agile process. I have work items such as bugs, features, etc. Please notice that I can actually see bugs in my KanBan board as I did the configuration to show bugs in there.

#### Problem

Problem is that if my bugs have the root area *MyArea*, they are shown in the board, but if I set a subarea `MyArea/Subarea`, the bug disappears from the board.

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That`s may depend on your team settings. As example, you can enable sub-areas in your root area:

[image]

Or add every every area to the team areas that you want to see on your board.

Comment: Man thank you so much! DevOps is unfortunately quite unintuitive though I really like it!